# web.xml vs context.xml in web app deployed on Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, configuration

What is the difference between web.xml and context.xml?? I saw one web application in which Database related info was given in context.xml. My question is we can also give the same information in web.xml in  tags then why use context.xml?? Is there any specific information which we cannot describe in "web.xml" so thats why we use "context.xml"??

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7761647/config-xml-vs-web-xml-in-web-application

Comment: Not cleared from that link. Exactly what is the difference between web.xml and xontext.xml files?? Is web.xml not enough?

Comment: @Coder9606 First line of that linked Answer tells you one major difference: web.xml is standard while context.xml is not standard (it is Tomcat specific).